# Batch script to wait for file to be generated on FTP server and download

Tags: file, batch-file, ftp, sftp

I have a program in my FTP server to generate a file, which may take 3-5 minutes to complete and also I knew the name of the file which i being created by my program. Now, once I initiate the program in my server, I have keep checking until the file is created. Once it is created, I am using the below batch script to ftp the file to my local desktop.

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open 10.100.16.111 
username
password
lcd c:\
cd  root/output_folder
binary
mget "*partial_file_name*" REM mget using wildcard search
disconnect
bye
```

This script works fine for me. But the problem is, I need modify this script as such, script should keep running until the file is generated. Because i don't know when the file creation will get completed. So, it will great if some one help/guide me to make a looping script which will wait until the completion of file creation and download the same file through FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this edit you can launch the batch file with the file name on the command line, like this:

```
ftpscript.bat "filename.ext"
```

Note that your **lcd** uses `c:\` which is a restricted location in later versions of windows.

```
@echo off
 >file.tmp echo open 10.100.16.111 
>>file.tmp echo username
>>file.tmp echo password
>>file.tmp echo lcd c:\
>>file.tmp echo cd  root/output_folder
>>file.tmp echo binary
>>file.tmp echo mget "%~1"
>>file.tmp echo disconnect
>>file.tmp echo bye

:retry
ftp -i -s:"file.tmp"
if not exist "%~1" timeout /t 300 & goto :retry
echo file has downloaded
del file.tmp
pause
```

Comment: Wow..thanks a lot foxdrive for your quick help. This works fine for me. But the thing is i need to hard code the file name in two places which are, ftp batch script and the next one you suggested. Is there a way to avoid that? or is it possible to give input dynamically?

Comment: Thanks foxidrive. This is doing what exactly i want.

Comment: Great.  Be aware that if you select a filespec* instead of a single file then it will end when any of the filespec are downloaded and the FTP portion quits - and perhaps not every file you expect has downloaded.

Comment: Hello @foxidrive Is it possible to modify the script to get multiple arguments from a text file and download the files based on the input?

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution is to use an FTP client that supports parametrized scripts or commands on command-line, such as WinSCP, to avoid creating a temporary script file.

### Parametrized script

The batch file would be more or less identical as with the Windows `ftp`:

```
@echo off
:retry
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter "%~1"
if not exist "%~1" timeout /t 300 & goto :retry
echo file has downloaded
pause
```

[The `ftp` script converts to following WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp):

```
open ftp://username:password@10.100.16.111/
lcd c:\
cd root/output_folder
get -transfer=binary "%1%"
exit
```

### Commands on command-line

You can also inline the commands the to the batch file:

```
@echo off
:retry
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@10.100.16.111/" ^
    "lcd c:\" ^
    "cd root/output_folder" ^
    "get -transfer=binary ""%~1""" ^
    "exit"
if not exist "%~1" timeout /t 300 & goto :retry
echo file has downloaded
pause
```

---

References:

- [Automating file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [Upload to multiple servers / Parametrized script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers).

Had you ever need to upgrade to the FTPS or the SFTP, just modify the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url) in the [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) command accordingly.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*